# How put query with openquery faster?

Tags: sql-server

this query takes a lot of time running.
Does anyone know anyway to put them faster?

```
    DECLARE @actual as INT
    DECLARE @expected as INT
    DECLARE @ID as INT
    DECLARE @TSQL varchar(100)
    DECLARE @t table (c int)
    DECLARE @Id_aux varchar(100)

    SET @ID = (select max(id) from [STG].table where fk_country = 5 )
    SET @Id_aux= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @ID)

    SET  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MA],''select count(*) from table where id <=' + @Id_aux + ''')'
    INSERT INTO @t EXEC (@TSQL)
    SET @expected = (select c from @t)

    SET @actual = (SELECT count(*) from [STG].table where fk_country = 5 and id<=@ID)

    select @expected
    select @actual
```

Thanks

Comment: Better indexing on your table `paybuddy_purchase_ex`?

Comment: No, I dont have index

Comment: So better indexing seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Do you have any ideia how create a index inside to openquery?

Comment: You don't. Connect to the other host and index the table there.

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't really know how to clarify. Connect **directly** to the other host (`BE_PAY_MA`), and then you need to index the table appropriately.

Comment: I see but I am not able to do that.

Comment: Then speak to whomever can...

Comment: Is there a notable difference between executing the query directly and using openquery? Or is your question really about the query and not anything to do with using openquery?

Comment: My question is about openquery. I do not have access to original table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use a different approach while executing queries via linked servers.

```
EXECUTE ... AT [Linked_Server];
```

Benefits:

- This way a query will be executed on the remote server. Guaranteed. Thus it will be much more performant.
- Very easy to pass parameters. No strings concatenation.

Useful link: [SQL Server: Execute At LinkedServer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36213.sql-server-execute-at-linkedserver.aspx)

Check it out below.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @actual as INT;
DECLARE @expected as INT;
DECLARE @ID as INT;
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(100);
DECLARE @t table (c int);
--DECLARE @Id_aux varchar(100);

SET @ID = (select max(id) from [PAY_STG].pay.paybuddy_purchase_ex where fk_country = 5 );
--SET @Id_aux= CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @ID);

--SET  @TSQL = 'SELECT * 
--  FROM OPENQUERY([BE_PAY_MA],
--  ''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paybuddy_purchase_ex WHERE id <=' + @Id_aux + ''')';
--INSERT INTO @t EXEC (@TSQL);

INSERT INTO @t
EXECUTE(N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paybuddy_purchase_ex WHERE id <= ?',
 @ID) AT [BE_PAY_MA];


SET @expected = (select c from @t);

SET @actual = (SELECT count(*) from [PAY_STG].pay.paybuddy_purchase_ex where fk_country = 5 and id<=@ID);

select @expected;
select @actual;
```

Comment: Is there any way to run the query faster? It seems a little bit slow.

Comment: The `EXECUTE .. AT` is a fastest method. As many pointed out earlier, it should be an index on the remote table **paybuddy_purchase_ex**, column **id**. Please check with your DBAs.

Comment: I see bu for instance I have a query that takes more than 20 min to run. It is very time.